# how to use php IF looping to show value of a variable that taken from method GET on previous link?

Tags: php, if-statement, htmlspecialchars, get-method

```
<?php
include "global_database_function.php"; //include config file
$nama_kategori = $_GET['nama_kategori']; //get from previous link
//global $nama_kategori; 
//i can't use global $name_kategori

$idkategori = $_GET['idkategori'];
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//continue only if $_POST is set and it is a Ajax request
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{   
  //here is the code i try to show, i try to use:
   htmlspecialchars($nama_kategori);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

if I put `htmlspecialchars($nama_kategori);` between body and `if(isset($_POST) && isset`, the value of `$nama_kategori` is visible.

Comment: I'm confused, could you please clarify your issue?

Comment: First, `$_POST` is **always** set. It's a superglobal, it's set at runtime, so your verification will be true no matter what. Test `$_POST` for emptiness (and beware that it may fail as well, since the submit button - if any - count as form element), or use `isset` on a specific post field (eg `if (isset($_POST['idkategori']));`)

Comment: @Epodax i'm sorry, i have problem, I can not bring up the value `$nama_kategori` taken from the previous file links.
if I put `$nama_kategori` between the body and if, the value fetched from the previous file links can be raised. but after I put `$nama_kategori` in a `IF(isset($_POST)` conditional, the value does not appear

Comment: Second: `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])` there is no such field on `$_SERVER` as `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` unlees you have set it before, hardcoded, and didn't show us. If you did (I hope you did), it will evaluate to true even if it's empty. `isset` evaluates true if the variable **exists**, while `empty` does the same if the var contains something.

Comment: Then that's because it doesn't enter the if clause

Comment: maybe you are missning `echo` ?? `echo htmlspecialchars($nama_kategori);`

Comment: Third: [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) returns a **string** and not a boolean, so it won't be evaluated as true or false. [**EDIT**: I stand corrected on this one, I didn't scrolled the code to the left to see you were comparing it to a string, my bad...]

Comment: Conclusion: you're using `if` statement the wrong way.

Comment: Anyway I'm voting your question as *unclear what you're asking*, because it is. Please, consider taking the site's [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the Help Center to learn about [how to make questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Let it store into session for future as

```
$nama_kategori = $_GET['nama_kategori'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['t']=$nama_kategori;
```

and when needed

```
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{ 
session_start();  
echo $_SESSION['t'];
}
```